# Test Blocked Categories on Proxy

Tags: powershell, proxy

I am trying to see/test blocked categories on a proxy. I have written a script that work and I get the expected results but when i try to use credentials, i get the same results. The credentials I am using, are for a user that should have access to some categories that are normally blocked for regular users but i am getting the same results as regular users. I have double checked that the user is a part of an exclusion group but doesn't seem to work.For example, without creds, sites such as facebook are blocked, but with the creds it should be allowed. When i manually set the proxy on a machine using the creds i am able to navigate to facebook so i know the creds work. I just don't know how to get them to work in the script.

```
#Setting proxies 
$prox1 = "Proxy1"
$prox2 = "Proxy2"

#Setting Credentials
$Users = "Username"
$pass = "Passowrd"

foreach($User in $Users){

$file =  $User + ".csv"
echo "Category`tProxy1`tProxy2`tEqual`tSite" >> $file

#Setting categories to check
$cats = "Bluecoat Test Pages"
#Setting credentials
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $User, $Password 

#For each category test using both proxies          
foreach($cat in $cats)  {

#Creating new system object proxy and setting it to use first proxy
    $proxy = new-object System.Net.WebProxy($prox1) 
#Setting credentials
    $proxy.credentials = $cred
#Creating new web client
    $WebClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
#Making web client use set proxy
    $WebClient.proxy = $proxy


#splits site from category name
    $cat = $cat.split("-")
    $cat_name = $cat[0]
    $site = $cat[1]

    write-host $cat_name
#tries to download site html    
    try{                                                                                      
        $html1=$WebClient.downloadstring($site)                              
    }   
#if exception then wasnt able to download html and was blocked  
    catch [system.exception]{
        write-host "`tBlocked -" $prox1 -ForegroundColor Red
        $rp1 = "Blocked"
    }
#if html has content then site was accessible and is allowed
    if($html1){ 
        write-host "`tAllowed -"  $prox1 -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $rp1 = "Allowed"        
    }

#Above process repeats for second proxy.

    if($rp1 -eq $rp2){
        $equal = "TRUE"
    }
    else{
        $equal = "FALSE"
    }
    echo "$cat_name`t$rp1`t$rp2`t$equal`t$site" >> $file

    $html1 = ""
    $html2 = ""
    $rp1 = ""
    $rp2 = ""
}
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

Comment: The error you are getting is unclear, Are you getting things showing as blocked when they should be allowed or the other way around?

Comment: I am getting the same results as if I never used credentials. For example, without creds, sites such as facebook are blocked, but with the creds it should be allowed. When i manually set the proxy on a machine using the creds i am able to navigate to facebook so i know the creds work. I just dont know how to get them to work in the script